# increment the contents of array when match is found

Tags: c

```
main()
{

   int  i,j,mul_count[16]={0},mul;

   int *ptr;

   ptr =&mul_count;

   for(i=1;i<=4;i++)    
   {
         for(j=1;j<=4;j++)

         mul = j*i;

         ptr = (ptr+(mul*4));

         mul_count[mul] = ++*ptr;
   }

   for(i=1;i<=16;i++)    
      printf("mul_count[%d]=%d\n",i,mul_count[i]);

}
```

can any one correct this code. The code is i generate multiple for all possible combination from 1 to 4,and increment the array contents for that particular value, i.e when i do 2*2 = 4 and 4*1=4 , then mul_count[4] should be set a 2 and so on, when i encounter 4 again in the multiples it should be incremented to 3 and so on.this has to be done for all generated multiples that corresponding array value should be incremented

Comment: What's wrong with `mul_count[WHATEVER]++;`?

Comment: I think you're missing some braces for the code that should be in your inner loop.

Comment: Arrays starts from index = 0, but not 1. The last element in array mul_count[16] has index 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any point in your usage of the `ptr` variable.

Also your code misses the required brackes `{` and `}` for the inner loop. You can get away much easier with something like this instead:

```
for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=4;j++) {
        mul = j*i;
        mul_count[mul]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be mul_count[mul-1]++;

Comment: or an extension of the size of `mul_count`. True, but that's why I only gave an excerpt of the code as that's left up to personal perference or other requirements.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have forgot braces for your second loop.
2. ptr is always incremented, so you are going out of your array. Anyway this pointer is really not need.

Try this:

```
for(j=1; j<=4; ++j)
{
    mul = j*i - 1;
    mul_count[mul]++;
}
```